# Model attributes set in beforeSave() are not being saved

Tags: php, yii, before-save

I am trying to set a model attributes in beforeSave() method but they are not saved afterwards.

```
 public function beforeSave(){
     if(!$this->isNewRecord){
         // ...
         $this->status = self::VISIBLE;
     }               
     return parent::beforeSave();
 }
```

I have tried returning true instead of parent::beforeSave().
Also I have tried if(parent::beforeSave) {} structure.

I have checked model attributes in afterSave and they are set. I just don't get there they can get lost afterwards.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to update the model without X-editable plugin and the additional attributes were set in beforeSave().

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are updating a model above..

if(!$this->isNewRecord).

Remove this conditin while saving with status field

Comment: beforeSave() is fired also when the model is created, thus I don't want the status changes for new models. The thing is, I checked model attributes with xdebug and they are set.

Comment: Give Some More Explanation about your model save|update

Comment: The model is being updated using x-editable plugin. So whenever the model is updated I use beforeSave() to check which values where updated. If the 'right' value was updated I set a different status for the model. Strange thing is that the original values changed are being saved, except the status attribute which I set in beforeSave()

Comment: value of const|static   VISIBLE ? ..what are database status entry when new Entry saved and value of status column after a entry is updated in your database